# Anonymously Instantiate UIButton in Array

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I am making a sudoku game with Swift and iOS. The game has a 9 x 9 grid of UIButtons that serve as the game board. I am looking for a way to anonymously declare those buttons in an array or some other collection so I can interact with them, check validity, etc.

Is there a way to do this without ctrl-dragging form the scene to my ViewController for each button, declaring each as a named instance of UIButton, then operating on them in that method? This is the only way that I can think of to interact with them in some structured basis, but it is ugly and unmaintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating an outlet connection. Or you can set the tag of each the buttons to a number, and search for them.

```
for subview in self.view.subviews {
    if subview.tag == aNumber {
        buttons.append(subview as! UIButton)
    }
}
```

Make sure to call this in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: Adding tags is a great idea and should solve my problem, thanks.